# Moving an asp.net ADFS/AD site

Tags: asp.net, adfs

If I'm copying an asp.net site that uses ADFS / AD for authentication, do I need to re-run fedutil.exe from the new server (windows 2012)? The new location will have a different url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The endpoint has changed so yes you need to make changes.

FedUtil (IIRC) just adds all the WIF plumbing so re-running it won't help.

Easiest is just to change the endpoint in the ADFS RP configuration.